# replace all the vowels in a mysql column with a random vowel

Tags: mysql, sql, random, obfuscation

I have a mysql database with the table Clients and would like to hide my sensitive data (to give the database to a developper) by replacing all the vowels of the FirstName and LastName columns by random vowels.

So all the "A", "E", "I", "O", "U" found in the string should be replaced by a random letter in the group "A", "E", "I", "O", "U".

Identically all the "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" should be replaced by a random letter in the group "a", "e", "i", "o", "u".

Thanks for you answer.

Comment: try something similar to postgresql translate() : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not pretty but i works.

```
SELECT name,
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
        name,'a',mid('aeiuoy',rand()*5+1,1))
            ,'e',mid('aeiuoy',rand()*5+1,1))
            ,'i',mid('aeiuoy',rand()*5+1,1)) 
            ,'u',mid('aeiuoy',rand()*5+1,1)) 
            ,'o',mid('aeiuoy',rand()*5+1,1)) 
            ,'y',mid('aeiuoy',rand()*5+1,1)) 
        as codedname
FROM names;
```

If you want to replace more randomly, you should create a function as this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fReplaceVowels`(s varchar(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
declare v_max int unsigned;
declare v_counter int unsigned default 1;
declare result varchar(255);

set result = s;
set v_max = LENGTH(s);

  while v_counter < v_max do
    if (select binary  'aeiuoy' like concat('%', mid(s,v_counter,1),'%') ) then
        set result=concat(left(result,v_counter-1),mid('aeiuoy',rand()*5+1,1),mid(result,v_counter+1));
    end if;
    if (select binary  'AEIUOY' like concat('%', mid(s,v_counter,1),'%') ) then
        set result=concat(left(result,v_counter-1),mid('AEIUOY',rand()*5+1,1),mid(result,v_counter+1));
    end if;
    set v_counter=v_counter+1;
  end while;
RETURN result;
END
```

Use it like this:

```
SELECT name, fReplaceVowels(name) as codedname FROM names;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well! Just a little issue. All the vowels of the string are replaced by the same random vowel. Could you edit this request to make those vowels in one string to be replaced by different random vowels? Thanks a lot

Comment: I added a function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work,

```
select translate('The quick brown fOx jumps ovEr the lazy 
dog','aeiouAEIOU','eiouaEIOUA');

                  translate                  
---------------------------------------------
 Thi qaock bruwn fUx jamps uvIr thi lezy dug
```

`translate(column, to_string, from_string)` -  For from_string, you can specify the alphabets in anyorder. 
Refer to the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

But a character can be replaced by only one character, 
i.e 'a' will be replaced by 'e', etc.